# HTTP Basic Authorization Network Issue on Android

Tags: java, android, rest, networking, android-studio

I'm having a problem querying a database in Ragic off of Android. I've SUCCESSFULLY created a program in Eclipse that queries the online database and downloads all the JSONS, turns them into Objects, and then puts them into an ArrayList. Unfortunately, I'm running into a problem trying to download the same data using the exactly same code in Android. I've already added the permission for the internet (as shown in the AndroidManifest.xml). The code compiles and all, but throws the NullPointerException("RUNTIME EXCEPTION/ALLDOWNLOADEXCEPTIONS") at the end of the MapsActivity.java file. That is the problem, but I don't know what it causing it. Please help with that.

Here is the MapsActivity.java:

```
package com.main.parcaretestversion;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polygon;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptions;
import com.google.gson.*;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    ArrayList<ParkingSpot> list = init();

    System.exit(0);
    for (ParkingSpot spot: list) {
        PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
                .addAll(spot.getArrayListLatLngDefault());
        if (spot.getStatus()) {
            rectOptions.fillColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            rectOptions.fillColor(Color.RED);
        }
        Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
    }
}
public ArrayList<ParkingSpot> format(String input) {
    ArrayList<ParkingSpot> list = new ArrayList<ParkingSpot>();
    JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(input);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        String uid = root.getAsJsonObject().get(String.valueOf(i) + "").getAsJsonObject().get("ID").getAsString();
        String coordinate1 = root.getAsJsonObject().get(String.valueOf(i) + "").getAsJsonObject().get("Coordinate 1").getAsString();
        String coordinate2 = root.getAsJsonObject().get(String.valueOf(i) + "").getAsJsonObject().get("Coordinate 2").getAsString();
        String coordinate3 = root.getAsJsonObject().get(String.valueOf(i) + "").getAsJsonObject().get("Coordinate 3").getAsString();
        String coordinate4 = root.getAsJsonObject().get(String.valueOf(i) + "").getAsJsonObject().get("Coordinate 4").getAsString();
        String statusTemp = root.getAsJsonObject().get(String.valueOf(i) + "").getAsJsonObject().get("Status").getAsString();
        boolean status;
        if (statusTemp.equals("true")) {
            status = true;
        } else {
            status = false;
        }
        list.add(new ParkingSpot(uid, status, new LatLong(coordinate1), new LatLong(coordinate2), new LatLong(coordinate3), new LatLong(coordinate4)));
    }
    return list;
}
public ArrayList<ParkingSpot> init() {
    String apiKey = "some api key";
    try {
        //
        URL url = new URL("https://api.ragic.com/some username/some sheet/1");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + apiKey);
        InputStream content = (InputStream) connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String uglyJson = "";
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
            uglyJson += line;
        }
        ArrayList<ParkingSpot> list = format(uglyJson);
        throw new NullPointerException(uglyJson);
        //return list;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new NullPointerException("MALFORUMED URL EXCEPTION");
    } catch (RuntimeException allDownloadExceptions) {
        throw new NullPointerException("RUNTIME EXCEPTION/ALLDOWNLOADEXCEPTIONS");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        throw new NullPointerException("PROTOCOL EXCEPTION");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new NullPointerException("IO EXCEPTION");
    }
}
}
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Don't use main thread for network operations. Use services or asyctasks

Answer (score 1):

Use asyncTasks in your mainActivity.

For example.

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList> {
        @Override
        protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params) {
               URL url = new URL("https://api.ragic.com/some username/some sheet/1");

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + apiKey);
    InputStream content = (InputStream) connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
    String uglyJson = "";
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
        uglyJson += line;
    }
    ArrayList<ParkingSpot> list = format(uglyJson);
    throw new NullPointerException(uglyJson);
    return list;
            }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList result) {
            //Handle result here.
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }


   }
```

now make call for this call

```
   new LongOperation().execute();
```

Hope it will help

Comment: I'm relatively new to Java, could you please explain how and where I would implement the HTTP REST Query?

Comment: @fedorp1 your query would go inside of the "doInBackground" method. "onPostExecute" will be called with the returned data as the "result" parameter.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Note you will have to handle result in onPostExcute method.

Comment: OK, I've put the method into a new LongOperation.java file, and the format method (since it is needed for the doInBackground method) I've also put in the same file. Now, I'm getting an error like this: http://postimg.org/image/xutcmf65t/

Comment: I have updated answer you need to add ArrayList instead of List in return type.

Comment: OK, Implemented the entire new class, I can give you a picture of the code if you need it, but now I'm getting two new errors, pictured here: http://postimg.org/image/t3mvltxxp/. @ZeeshanShabbir thanks for all your help by the way!

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir Actually, nevermind! That's not the real problem. What the real problem that's causing the app to crash right now is a NullPointerException when the class tries to create an iterator to iterate through the enhanced-for-loop and initialize the map. So, somehow the list isn't transferring to the main class. By the way, I made the Async class private and pasted it into the main MapsActivity, but I don't think that is the problem. Somehow, the List isn't initializing. Here's an image with the error: http://postimg.org/image/vmogut21l/.

Comment: Post the whole mainActivity Code. I think onMapReady gets fired before the before result from server. show me all of your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100266/discussion-between-fedorp1-and-zeeshan-shabbir).

Comment: Any solution by any chance?